# Cassandra table structure for query to get all usernames

Tags: performance, cassandra, querying

In my cassandra database I have a table with users and I want a function to search for users by their unique usernames. For that I need to query all usernames from the user table so that I can filter them serverside, because for input of "nark" I should also find username "Mark", "Narkis" and so on, so I can't just use the username as a partition key and search for the exact value.

If I give them all in the same partition, it results in a hot partition. If I distribute them over multiple partitions, I have to search in all of them.

How can query that efficiently for millions of users? Is there a way to search like that without querying all usernames?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'd recommend using ElasticSearch for this.  Cassandra is _not_ a search engine, and won't respond well to search use cases.  Elastic has built-in functionality for things like fuzzy matching, and will do a much better job of handling this use case.

Comment: For OLAP (Online analytical processing) kind of queries, use tools like Spark to query Cassandra. They can efficiently query Cassandra in case of full scan of tables is required.

Here you are required to scan list of users from complete table and filter users from that list at client side.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra natively is not a good fit for such a use case. Even extensive use of secondary indexes will be of minimal help here.

Nevertheless if you already have all your data on C* to achieve such a functionality you essentially need a indexing framework on top of it, most widely used is Apache SOLR (built on Lucene).I have seen SOLR work like magic for fuzzy searching on C* though nothing beats having something like Elasticsearch for the use case.